# How do I stack buttons in Materialize css?

Tags: css, html, materialize

I am working with the Materialize css Framework and after reviewing the documentation provided I cannot figure out how to stack elements.

My code is provided below.

http://pastebin.com/EUchUefx

[the output is this](http://postimg.org/image/madgwvop3/)

How would I stack the two buttons on top of one another?

In addition, what would be the proper way to stack elements in general using this framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your markup to:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s3 grey darken-1">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">FreePBX initial Setup</a>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">FreePBX Advanced Setup</a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="col s4">
        <div>
            <p class="flow-text">FreePBX tech was created for beginners or experts of the open source pbx system. Read our documents or watch our help videos to learn how to use the latest version of FreePBX.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[PasteBin Here](http://pastebin.com/B5sy5VW0)

Comment: Thank you, so my issue was that I used two separate columns for my buttons instead of keeping them in the same.

Comment: @spoon_seth Exactly! I'm glad to help.